# Understanding a function call that uses EAX before and after for the return value

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, calling-convention

I have been trying to hook a function which is mostly optimized by the compiler. It initializes **EAX** before the call and its return value is stored in **EAX**.

Here is some code:

```
mov eax,dword ptr ds:[0xA6DD08]
push 0x3DC                     
add eax,0x800                  
call 0x48A2B4  
mov esi,eax
```

At first, 0xA6DD08 is a pointer to some data in memory but once adding 0x800, **EAX** just points to a value of **zero** but the next few DWORD(s) stores pointer of pointers or data array. The function's purpose itself is to lookup and return a specific object that has a DWORD variable equal to the given value which is 0x3DC.

When using **__asm** to call the function from my dll, it works perfectly but I am trying to write it in c++, something like

```
Class1*  pClass = reinterpret_cast<Class1*(__stdcall*)(DWORD)>(0x48A2B4)(988);
```

I believe from what I read that only **__stdcall** uses **EAX** to store its return value and that's why I choose **__stdcall** calling convention. What I do not understand is the purpose of **EAX** before calling the function.

Comment: 1) Why is this question tagged "C++"? 2) why would you want to write something in inline ASM rather than express what you want in a higher level language and let the *compiler* worry about the ASM? - You can rarely outdo the optimizing compiler as far as generating optimal ASM (and even when you can, it usually doesn't matter performance wise in any real applications).

Comment: I am not trying to do what the compiler does, I am just trying to hook the function properly with c++ code in my DLL.

Comment: Have you examined the object code of the function itself?  What is it expecting in `EAX`?

Comment: I did and as I said it just points to a location in memory where it's value is just ZERO. But the function it self uses the data right after what EAX have which I believe is more like a pointer of pointers or an array of pointers. Basically the function purpose is to lookup an object inside a list or smth

Comment: It is not uncommon for 32-bit compilers to expect the first few parameters in `eax`, `edx`, `ecx`, assuming they fit, for _fast_ calling conventions.

Comment: All x86 calling conventions return in EAX, not just `__stdcall`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError ye, well that's what driving me crazy. It's been more tha 5 days trying to figure out what's actually happening there! and, it's definitaly not a fastcall since it pushs an argument. The function is being called by several locations and they all just do the same with EAX.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I think only [GCC `regparm`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html) uses EAX, EDX, ECX for arg passing.  (e.g. `gcc -mregparm=3`).  MS `__fastcall` uses ECX, EDX, but not EAX.  `__thiscall` uses ECX, I think.  I might be forgetting about some 32-bit convention used on Windows that does pass something in EAX, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the info, I might have been mistaken about this info. I will do more researches about the return val register !

Comment: Agner Fog's calling convention doc is pretty good.  https://agner.org/optimize/.  I don't know why you'd have code doing something to EAX before a `call`.  It's not an input to a normal `__stdcall` function.  But I think it's you making up the `__stdcall`; this function might actually be GCC regparm=1 which would pass in EAX and then the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just read a quick info from your links about GCC regparm which seems to be my problem here. I will do more reading, apply and test, hope that's really the case. I will let you know if that's it so you can write an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

`add eax,0x800` right before a `call` wouldn't make sense unless EAX is an input to the called function.

Passing 1 arg in EAX and another on the stack looks to me like GCC's [`regparm=1` calling convention](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html).  Or if other regs are set before this, `regparm=3` passes in EAX, EDX, and ECX (in that order).

32-bit x86 builds of the Linux kernel are typically built with `-mregparm=3`, but user-space GNU/Linux code typically follows the clunky old i386 System V convention which passes all args on the stack.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions, a couple other obscure calling conventions also pass a first arg in EAX:

- Delphi and Free Pascal `register`: EAX, EDX, ECX (Left-to-right Pascal style arg passing, right-most arg in EAX I guess?  Unlike GCC regparm)
- Watcom compiler: EAX, EDX, EBX, ECX.  Unless you left out some setting of EDX, EBX, and ECX before pushing a stack arg, we can rule that out.

---

> only __stdcall uses EAX to store it's return value

Actually, *all* x86 calling conventions do that for integer args, across the board.  Also both x86-64 conventions.  See [Agner Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) calling convention guide.

Comment: I am afraid this is not the case here, both my dll and the target exe are compiled with visual c++ (MSVC) where regparm is not an option. After more digging, I am kinda certain that 0xA6DD08 points to an object of maps and add eax, 0x800 just gets eax to a specific map to start the lookup.

Comment: @Muhab: Ok, so visual C++ can't generate asm compatible with the calling convention your DLL is using.  Too bad. :/  Your options are MSVC inline asm, or switching compilers to GCC, clang, or maybe ICC so you can use `__attribute__((regparm(1)))` on that function.